# Google Drive API to get folder list using Parent Id

Tags: google-api, google-drive-api

I am trying to get all folders under a google drive folder using parent folder id

using below api

content.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files/

passing parent id in request body

am able to create files and folders under parent id, but when try to get folder list in parent folder its giving me error as bad request

Note: I am using postman tool

Comment: Can you show your query?

Comment: this is the api am using  

https://content.googleapis.com/driv/v3/files?parents=10oCPwjGlp8ArZGP0nk2jnvztniaCRdH4

Comment: And with this request you can retrieve files but not folders?

Comment: I can't retrieve both files and folders under parent folder using parent id in parameter is there any alternative solutions for this?

Answer (score 1):

### If you want to use a [query](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-files) when listing results, the syntax is `'1234567' in parents`, not `parents=1234567`

In your case, the correct syntax would be something like

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=%2710oCPwjGlp8ArZGP0nk2jnvztniaCRdH4%27%20in%20parents
```